# paused workflow on item change

Tags: workflow

I don't have enough points to comment on this post so I am posting a new question: [What happens to a paused workflow when the item is changed?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/133137/what-happens-to-a-paused-workflow-when-the-item-is-changed).

I have a workflow that runs on item change. It pauses for 24 hours. While it is paused, if the user edits the item, I assume the workflow continues to run?

I think that is what the above post is saying but I was looking for clarification.

And will a 2nd instance of the workflow spawn because the item was changed or because it is still running it won't?

The list has versifying so when the item is changed a new version is created. Not sure if that changes anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the item is modified, the existing workflow instance continues to run, by which I mean it will stay paused and will still resume 24 hours after it originally paused. A second instance of the same workflow will not be created, *unless* the workflow itself has been changed - an item can only have one instance of a given workflow running on it at a time, but different *versions* of a workflow aren't considered the same workflow for this logic. If you have modified the workflow and you go to the workflow settings page for the item, you will see [workflow name] - (previous version [timestamp]) in the list of running workflows.